# How do you create a JFace tree view for a particular file extension(eg. all .doc files) in the file system

Tags: jface

If the parent folder does not contain any files of this extension it will appear in the tree but will not be expandable since no files of this type exist

Comment: This is far too broad. Are you asking about just viewing an ordinary file system using the Java `File` or `Path` APIs, or are you asking about something like an Eclipse workspace? Most of the tree viewer code will follow the usual pattern for any viewer - so what have you tried?

Comment: I have used Java's File API. Implementation so far :

Comment: So show us what you have tried.